# Raíz cuadrada de un BigInteger o BigDecimal en Java

Tags: java

Buenas, he intentado sacar la raíz de un `BigInteger` con el método `pow` de `BigInteger`, porque no encuentro el método que realice la operación de raíz cuadrada a las instancias de esta clase.

```
BigInteger sqr = n.pow(0.5);
```

Sin embargo el método `pow` de `BigInteger` solo recibe enteros. Si hay una forma o si el método para sacar la raíz cuadrada de un `BigInteger` si existe, les agradecería me lo aclararan, gracias.

Comment: Me temo que no hay implementaciones nativas de Java para pow con decimales, se puede convertir a BigInteger a BigDecimal, pero quedas en las mismas, ninguna recibe decimal :P. Hay varias preguntas de este tipo en SOen http://stackoverflow.com/q/3579779/6658955 http://stackoverflow.com/q/16441769/6658955

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static BigInteger raiz(BigInteger x) {
    BigInteger a= BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(x.bitLength()/2);
    BigInteger b= a;
    while(true) {
        BigInteger c = a.add(x.divide(a)).shiftRight(1);
        if (c.equals(a) || c.equals(b))
            return c;
        b= a;
        a= c;
    }
}
```

es algo muy parecido a un ataque por fuerza bruta.
primero elegimos un punto de comienzo, en este caso usamos las propiedades del sistema binario de tal manera que el valor del bit de la mitad de la longitud total es en los casos que se tiene raíz cuadrada entera, por ejemplo:

```
2->4
4->16
8->64
16->256
```

luego solo iteramos, si x/a=a entonces a*a=x.

por ejemplo: 81

```
BigInteger a= BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(x.bitLength()/2);
```

en binario es 1010001, tiene 7 dígitos, la mitad seria 4, 1000 en decimal es 8.

iniciamos la a iterar:

```
x=81
a=8
b=8

c=(a+(x/a))/2
c=(8+(81/8))/2
c=(8+(10))/2
c=(18)/2
c=9

b=8
a=9
```

---

```
c=(a+(x/a))/2
c=(9+(81/9))/2
c=(9+(9))/2
c=(9)/2
c=9

c.equals(a)

return 9
```

Comment: Jorge , sería genial que brindarás una breve explicación del método. qué realiza y a que resultado llega. Gracias

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con Dev. Joel, tambien me gustaria saber como funciona, tengo nociones basicas acerca de bits. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: La solución esta basado en [Newtons method](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Newton). sería bueno de elaborar un poco. Básicamente se usa convergencia de acercarse rápidamente al resultado, una "adivinación cualificada".

Comment: @VictorPaternina he extendido la respuesta, pero para que requieres la raíz de un Biginteger?